# MySql Error at mysql_fetch_array():

Tags: php, mysql

I am collecting data on FB and sending it to my DB. My app is running, and I can see the data is inserted on my DB, but I am getting an error that I dont know how to solve. I have researched for this and tried some solutions without results. I added a line of code to see what was the error. Please guide me to solve it. Thanks

Error:

```
 Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
```

The error points me at this line:

```
 $result = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die ( mysql_error () );
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
define('db_user','xxx');
define('db_password','xxx');
define('db_host','xxx.xxx.com');
define('db_name','xxx');

// Connect to MySQL
 $dbc = @mysql_connect (db_host, db_user, db_password) OR die ('Could not connect to      MySQL: ' . mysql_error() );
// Select the correct database
mysql_select_db (db_name) OR die ('Could not select the database: ' . mysql_error() );
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbc);

require 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'xxxx',
'secret' => 'xxxx',
  'cookie' => true));


// Get User ID
 $user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$fbuid = $facebook->getUser();
 $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');



   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   error_log($e);
   $user = null;
   }
     }else{
   header('Location: index.php');

    }

      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND     oauth_uid = ". $user_profile['id']);  
      $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);  


    if(empty($result)){ 
      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, first_name, last_name, birthday, email, pic_square ) VALUES    ('facebook', {$user_profile['id']}, '{$user_profile['name']}', '{$user_profile['first_name']}','{$user_profile['last_name']}','{$user_profile['birthday']}','{$user_profile['email']}', '{$user_profile['pic_square']}')");  
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());  
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die ( mysql_error () );  


 }  


   // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($user) {
     $paramsout = array('next'=>'http://www.mywebsite.com/test/logout.php');
     $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($paramsout);
     }
     ?>
     <html><body>welcome</body></html>
```

Comment: do you actually have an 'id' column in your 'users' table?

Comment: off topic, but it is strongly recommended to stop using the obsolete `mysql_xxx()` functions. The PHP manual recommends switching your code to either using the equivalent `mysqli_xxx()` functions or the PDO library.

Comment: Hi! I already add the ID column. Now the problem I have is that every time the user goes to the app it will record the info again to the table, having a repeated data. how can i solve this part?

Comment: @Spudley Thanks for the recommendation, but I have no knowledge on programming at all. I have done this by reading and copying from everywhere. If you can send me a ling to read about how to change it, i will appreciate! Thanks

Comment: Try this one: http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: @Spudley, do you have any idea of why im getting repeating data on my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the query that fails is this one:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());
```

As the error message says, the table `users` doesn't contain a field called `id`.

Check the field name in the database, update the query and it should work.

Comment: Thanks My friend. I add the field ID and the error disappeared. The problem now is that every Time i visit the page, my database collects all the data and repeat it. Do you know why is this happening and how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Do you actually have a column named id? Check to make sure this is indeed what you named the column.

If you don't have a column named id you can add using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST
```

With AUTO_INCREMENT the column 'id' will automatically assign a new id number to each row you insert into the database, and the code you presented here will work.

Comment: Hi! I already add the ID column. Now the problem I have is that every time the user goes to the app it will record the info again to the table, having a repeated data. how can i solve this part?

Comment: Do a query for the data being inserted. So if I enter test@example.com your code should do a SELECT query on the database and, if one or more results are returned (meaning test@example.com exists in the database), reject the request as a duplicate.